# When to use "this" in variable assignment

Tags: c#

If i use "this" it makes `MainInst` the passed instance;  If I don't type this. wont it still make the variable equivalent to the same instance..? whats the point of this and when is it used in this type of assignment.

```
 class Phonebook
{
    private MainWindow MainInst;

    public Phonebook(MainWindow MainInstance){
        this.MainInst = MainInstance;
    }

}
```

vs

```
 class Phonebook
{
    private MainWindow MainInst;

    public Phonebook(MainWindow MainInstance){
        MainInst = MainInstance;
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case it won't matter. If you had `private MainWindow MainInstance;` however it would matter. A lot.

Comment: Only obligatory when there are name conflict between instance members and local variables.

Comment: Imagine if `MainInst = MainInstance;` did what you proposed. `x = y` would be `y = y`.

Comment: Side note: particular coding guidelines may require to always use `this.` prefix for all members. It may apply to your question if you see this code in large code-base that routinely using `this.` prefix whether it strictly required or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it doesn't matter because it is unambigous.

But if you had:

```
class Phonebook
{
    private MainWindow MainInst;

    public Phonebook(MainWindow MainInst){
        MainInst = MainInst;
    }
}
```

Then the code wouldn't be correct anymore. It would assign the parameter to itself. You'd have to use `this` to correct it.

My advice: use a different naming convention for classes, locals and private members. One example would be:

```
class Phonebook
{
    private MainWindow _mainInst;

    public Phonebook(MainWindow mainInst){
        _mainInst = mainInst;
    }
}
```

Now, you can see at first glance you're assigning a local variable (because it starts with a lower case letter) to a private member (because it starts with an underscore), without using `this`.

Note that, as per Alexei's comment, this in only one of many possible conventions. Microsoft suggests [these guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for *public* classes/members.  The widely accepted convention in C# code is that:

- Classes, properties and events should start with an uppercase letter
- Interfaces should start with `I` followed by an uppercase letter
- Locals should start with a lowercase letter.

None of these should contain underscores (except maybe for unit test methods).

As for the private members, there are many conventions, so pick your own.

- Some people prefer naming private members like local variables and they use `this` explicitly
- Some prepend an underscore like in my previous example
- Some use prefixes, like `my` or `m_` (Hungarian notation)...

Even Microsoft [uses Hungarian notation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#56) for their private members but [not consistently](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#2545). You should pick a convention and stick to it.

Comment: +1. Consider to make it clear that using prefix for members is one of many coding guidelines. Note that it is not part of .Net/C# [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggested by Microsoft - so following it for public samples (like once on SO) *may* get unnecessary attention to the style of the code, especially if inconsistently copy/pasted from multiple sources.

Comment: @Alexei Good point, but MS's guidelines don't apply to private members as they break them themselves. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "this" keyword is used when you have multiple variables of the same name in the same scope. For example, if your constructor had the signature `public Phonebook(MainWindow MainInst)`, then you would have to say `this.MainInst = MainInst` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: This answer is somehow wrong because it implies you can use `this` to change scope refence in any scope, while it does only change scope between local member inside instance method and instance member.